# Как скрыть элементы навигации Swiper.js

Tags: javascript, css, swiper, navigation, swiper.js

Итак, в чём суть. Библиотека Swiper сама убирает навигацию когда все элементы помещаются на экран и прокрутка не требуется. Но, мне нужно реализовать так, чтобы даже если они не помещаются, но, например, карусель стоит в начале (на первом элементе)  - не показывать левую кнопку навигации (Кнопка "Назад" или "Предыдущий"). Аналогично: скрыть кнопку "Вперёд" или "Следующий" когда докрутил карусель до конца.

Код инициализации Swiper:

```
  var swiper = new Swiper(".productMainSlider.vertuo > .woocommerce", {
    touch: false,
    direction: 'horizontal',
    slidesPerView: "auto",
    spaceBetween: 10,
    IOSEdgeSwipeDetection: true,
     onTouchStart: function()
    {
       return false;
    },
    scrollbarDraggable: true,
    scrollbarHide: true,
    grabCursor: true,
    freeMode: true,
    allowTouchMove: true,
    wrapperClass: 'products',
    slideClass: 'custom-theme-view',
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".productMainSlider.vertuo .swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".productMainSlider.vertuo .swiper-button-prev",
      lockClass: '.swiper-lock-step-navs'
    },
    scrollbar: {
    el: ".productMainSlider.vertuo .swiper-scrollbar",
    dragSize: '175',
    },
    watchOverflow: true,
    draggable: true,
    breakpoints: {
      1024: {
        slidesPerView: 4,
        slidesPerGroup: 4,
      }

    },
  });
```

Что я попробовал из рекомендованого документацией:

```
lockClass: '.swiper-lock-step-navs'
```

и указал в

```
.swiper-lock-step-navs {display:none;}
```

Так же я попробовал

```
watchOverflow: true
```

Может кто-то сталкивался, с такой задачей. Буду признателен намёком куда копать.
Заранее всем спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Решение было найдено на основе событий Swiper, а именно:
`reachEnd`, `reachBeginning` и `fromEdge`.

```
swiper.on('reachEnd', function() {
    var swjsNext = document.querySelector('.productMainSlider.vertuo .swiper-button-next');
    swjsNext.style.display = 'none'; 
});

swiper.on('reachBeginning', function() {
    var swjsPrev = document.querySelector('.productMainSlider.vertuo .swiper-button-prev');
    swjsPrev.style.display = 'none'; 
});

swiper.on('fromEdge', function() {
    var swjsNext = document.querySelector('.productMainSlider.vertuo .swiper-button-next');
    swjsNext.style.display = 'flex';
    var swjsPrev = document.querySelector('.productMainSlider.vertuo .swiper-button-prev');
    swjsPrev.style.display = 'flex';    
});
```

Comment: Т. е. стилями не получилось???
Городить комбайн js против трёх строк css легче и проще... Хм )))
<blockquote>
и указал в

.swiper-lock-step-navs {display:none;}
</blockquote>
Где вы это указывали?

Comment: Внимательно прочтите мой вопрос, а потом подумайте что Вы написали. Заодно поделитесь откуда в CSS известно о положении слайдов в текущей ситуации?

Comment: Евгений, вот именно, внимательно вникаем в вопрос вашей же задачи. Откуда, или лучше, для чего, зачем введён класс lockClass в настройках навигации? Ну и далее по коду вызова Свайпа + DevTools внимательно изучаем работу Свайпа и предпринимаем нужное решение и действия. Не нужно искать самый сложный путь. Всё на много проще.

Comment: Хорошо, предложите свой вариант решения, если несложно. Я его обязательно попробую

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, если слайдер находится в начале нужно скрыть кнопку **назад**, а если мы дошли до конца, то нужно скрыть кнопку **вперёд**.
В таком случае, чтобы скрыть кнопку, swiper даёт кнопке **назад** класс `swiper-button-disabled`. То же самое будет, если мы пролистаем все слайды - кнопка **вперёд** тоже получит данный класс.
Далее мы можем этому классу в стилях прописать какой-нибудь эффект или вовсе спрятать.

```
.swiper-button-disabled { display: none; };
```

[image: классы кнопки в DevTools]